# mysql if in where clause

Tags: mysql

This is probably very easy and just I'm being thick - I'm trying to stop reserved items from being picked up in the records but only if the stock is greater than 0, I can't work out how to do an unless

```
"....WHERE blah blah AND (reserved = 0 OR reserved < ".(time()-1200).")"
```

So the  column I'm looking at is called the "stock" column and if that value is 0 then I DO want to display the result

So I thought I could do

```
if(stock<>0,reserved = 0 OR reserved < ".(time()-1200.")
```

But that errors...

Comment: What defines a "reserved item"?

Comment: it's an item that has been timestamped by another user as being in their basket for purchase, I give them 20 minutes to buy it in the meantime I don't want to display those in the shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood but wont:

```
"WHERE blah blah AND (stock = 0 OR reserved = 0 OR reserved < ".(time()-1200).")))"
```

do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

you can't do assignments like that in an if() clause. The format is

```
if (condition, true_value, false_value)
```

Possibly something like this will do:

```
if (stock <> 0, 0, time()-1200) AS reserved
```

Comment: doesn't that go in the SELECT part though? I need it to be in the WHERE clause